# Can't find javers integration for quarkus projects

Tags: quarkus, javers

I am trying to integrate JaVers for auditing into quarkus but there are almost no resources.
Is this even supported?
Can anybody maybe point me to resources?

Comment: In general, we can use any dependency in quarkus as long as we do not compile natively. There is no dedicated quarkus or quarkiverse extension, so if we need native compilation, we would probably have to write the extension ourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard about quarkus. Definetly there is no special support for it in Javers. Javers is open source - if you want to create such feature in javers fell free to open a new design discussion here - https://github.com/javers/javers/discussions

Answer (score 1):

I had a look into the individual classes of `InstantiatingModule`, which implement with `#getImplementations()` a list of classes that need to be there in general for Reflection. From there on I grinded the missing classes by error messages. There could be still a difference depending on the MappingStyle (Field or Bean). Take this as a starting point:

```java
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.RegisterForReflection;

@RegisterForReflection(
    classNames = {
        "org.javers.core.JaversCore",
        "org.javers.core.commit.CommitFactory",
        "org.javers.core.commit.CommitIdFactory",
        "org.javers.core.commit.CommitSeqGenerator",
        "org.javers.core.commit.DistributedCommitSeqGenerator",
        "org.javers.core.diff.DiffFactory",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.ArrayChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.CollectionAsListChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.CorePropertyChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.DiffAppendersModule",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.HashWrapper",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.ListAsSetChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.ListToMapAppenderAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.MapChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.MapChangesToListChangesFunction",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.NewObjectAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.NodeChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.ObjectRemovedAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.OptionalChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.PropertyChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.ReferenceChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.SetChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.SimpleListChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.diff.appenders.ValueChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.core.graph.CollectionsCdoFactory",
        "org.javers.core.graph.LiveCdoFactory",
        "org.javers.core.graph.LiveGraphFactory",
        "org.javers.core.graph.ObjectAccessHookDoNothingImpl",
        "org.javers.core.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder",
        "org.javers.core.graph.ObjectHasher",
        "org.javers.core.graph.TailoredJaversFieldFactory",
        "org.javers.core.graph.TailoredJaversMethodFactory",
        "org.javers.core.json.JsonConverterBuilder",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ArrayChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ChangeTypeAdaptersModule",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ContainerChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ListChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.MapChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.NewObjectTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ObjectRemovedTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ReferenceChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.SetChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.change.ValueChangeTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotAssembler",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotStateDeserializer",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotStateTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CommitIdTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CommitMetadataTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CommitPropertiesConverter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CommitTypeAdaptersModule",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.DiffTypeDeserializer",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.GlobalIdTypeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.JsonElementFakeAdapter",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.object.GlobalIdFactory",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.AnnotationNamesProvider",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.AnnotationsNameSpace",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.BeanBasedPropertyScanner",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.ClassAnnotationsScan",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.ClassAnnotationsScanner",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.ClassScan",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.ClassScanner",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.FieldBasedPropertyScanner",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.JPAAnnotationsNameSpace",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.JaversAnnotationsNameSpace",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.PropertyScan",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.PropertyScanner",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.ScannerModule",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.scanner.TypeFromAnnotation",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ArrayType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ClassType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.CollectionType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ContainerType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.CustomComparableType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.CustomType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.DehydratedTypeFactory",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.DuckType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EntityType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EntityTypeFactory",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EnumerableType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.IgnoredType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.JaversType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.KeyValueType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ListAsSetType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ListType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ManagedType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.MapContentType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.MapType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.OptionalType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ParametrizedDehydratedType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.PrimitiveOrValueType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.PrimitiveType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.SetType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ShallowReferenceType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TokenType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeFactory",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeMapper",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeMapperEngine",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeMapperLazy",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.TypeMapperModule",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.UnknownType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ValueObjectType",
        "org.javers.core.metamodel.type.ValueType",
        "org.javers.core.snapshot.ChangedCdoSnapshotsFactory",
        "org.javers.core.snapshot.SnapshotDiffer",
        "org.javers.core.snapshot.SnapshotFactory",
        "org.javers.core.snapshot.SnapshotGraphFactory",
        "org.javers.guava.MultimapChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.guava.MultisetChangeAppender",
        "org.javers.repository.api.JaversExtendedRepository",
        "org.javers.repository.jql.ChangesQueryRunner",
        "org.javers.repository.jql.QueryCompiler",
        "org.javers.repository.jql.QueryRunner",
        "org.javers.repository.jql.ShadowQueryRunner",
        "org.javers.repository.jql.ShadowStreamQueryRunner",
        "org.javers.repository.jql.SnapshotQueryRunner",
        "org.javers.shadow.ShadowFactory",
    }
)
public class QuarkusJaversConfig {}
```